# How to make sure my function runs only once per click

Tags: javascript, jquery, functional-programming

```js
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    $('#buttonOne').click(function() {
      if(getOneOrTwo() === "one") {
        $('.firstObject').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $('.secondObject').css('visibility','visible');
      } else {
          alert("Sorry, wrong guess.");
      }
     }
     
     $('#buttonTwo').click(function() {
      if(getOneOrTwo() === "two") {
        $('.firstObject').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $('.secondObject').css('visibility','visible');
      } else {
          alert("Sorry, wrong guess.");
      }
  });
```

I have several playing cards on the screen, which all have diamonds above them. I have all the diamonds hidden at first. When the start button is clicked I want to have a diamond appear over the first card, and a random number to be selected where < 0.5 is set equal to red, and > 0.5 is equal to black. Then the user guesses if it will be red or black by clicking a black or red button. If they guess correctly, the diamond over the 1st card should be hidden and and a diamond will appear over the second card to indicate their progress in the game. If they're wrong, it should display an alert telling them they're wrong. It seems to work fine for the red button, but the black button causes the alert to continue to pop up every time I close the alert until it is correct, as if the button is being clicked constantly until it is correct.

Comment: `$( '#pick-red' ).click(function() {` adds another event handler EVERY time you click start

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56839486/edit) and then `[<>]` and create a [mcve]

Comment: Why did you call getCardColor(); outside of the pick-red and pick-black's click event? I don't think it is needed

Comment: @mplungjan `$( '#pick-black' ).click(` as well

Comment: It is really not clear what your diamond one, two etc is referring to. Could you please add the HTML so that at least we have a visual of what you are talking about? Not sure why you only have code to *hide* the element with class diamond. I guess you will not be seeing much of that diamond then...

Comment: I hope I edited my code so it is easier to understand and help. This is my first time using this site. I apologize for making a bad post. I'm just not sure how to figure this out on my own. I'll try to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: @messerbill obviously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generally not set a click handler *inside* another click handler. In most cases that is a code smell, like it is here.

You'll want to have the "Start" button *pick* the color (make the selection), but nothing more; at least don't assign a click handler to the other buttons here. It could work, but it's straightforward when you define the click handlers *outside* this particular "Start" click handler.

The red/blue click handlers should *not* pick the color (again), because then the user could try several times the same button until it would be right. It seems more logical that the selection is only made at the click of the "Start" button, after which the guessing of *that* particular card would happen.

So store the chosen card somewhere. Like this:

```
var selected = null; // No selection yet
$('#buttonOne, #buttonTwo').hide(); // Initially hide the guessing buttons.

$('#myButton').click(function() {
    selected = getOneOrTwo();
    $('#buttonOne, #buttonTwo').show(); // Now that we have a selection, allow guessing
});

$('#buttonOne').click(function() {
    if (selected === "one") {
        // here do what ever you want to do when the guess is right
    } else {
        alert("Sorry, wrong guess.");
    }
});

// Similarly for the other button
```